# Check whether an SVG rect is within an SVG path

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to figure out how to check if a rectangle is fully within an SVG path. Currently I am using SVGs isPointInFill() function to check if its corner points do so. But as you see, the pink square is visually not within the SVG path – but its corner points are, so it is labeled as "inside".

I need something like getIntersectionList() but for two SVGelements.

Does anyone knows a way to figure this out?

[image]

Edit: I found a solution.
Instead of Rect elements, I used Path elements. For paths I have .getTotalLength() and .getPointAtLength() – thats how I can get coords of the whole outline for each px.

Comment: You could try that with each border point, not just corners.

Comment: What is the purpose of checking the overlap?

Comment: @chrwahl The purpose is that in the end I will have a grid of rectangles constrained by a shape as a ClipPath mask. The user should then only be able to click on rectangles that are completely within the mask.

Comment: @RatajS yeah, but how to find all the imaginary border points?

Comment: @chrs It should be points with x 26 or 56 and y 18–45 combined with points with x 26–56 and y 18 or 45 for your pink square.

Comment: @RatajS Oh, yes. But that becomes difficult as soon as the square is rotated. I am currently looking for a way to determine points/coords on a diagonal line.

Comment: Ah ok, I just found out about getPointAtLength. Thats something I could work with :-)

Answer (score 0):

Brute force method - clone that SVG element, fill the path with black (and draw it last). Dump the resulting SVG into Canvas, if any pixels aren't white or black, check to see if they're the color of one of the rects.